# Update if exist in other table

Tags: oracle

I want to update column in table A if the value of column A1 exist in one column of B table for example B2

```
update A
set A1 = 'F'
WHERE  A1 in (SELECT B2 FROM B );
```

I tried somethig like this but no success, i tried too with exists

Comment: I don't see a good reason why your approch sould not work. It looks good to me. Could you paste the exact code you have tried to run? Does SELECT B2 From B Where B2 = A1 bring any results before you try it? Why do you think it did not work? Any error? Anyway, I would prefer Pawel's solution.

Comment: Unless your value is NULL, your query should just work.

Comment: What do you mean by "but no success"? Any error message? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve by using

```
update com_a_ent ss  set estado = 'F'
where (ss.ciudad,ss.calle,ss.numero)in 
                                  (select c.aent_city,c.aent_street,c.aent_number 
                                  from a_address_entities c
                                  where c.aent_city= ss.ciudad 
                                  and c.aent_street = UPPER(ss.calle)
                                  and c.aent_number = ss.numero )
```

Comment: This is an `EXISTS` subquery, in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most efficient method but I can't see a problem with your SQL.

Recommend you check your data..